# Each_with_index not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iterator, ruby-on-rails-3.2, each, carousel

I m using carousel to display the images. I ve uploaded the images in the cloud. But somehow it is repeating it self.
Here is my code

```
div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousell-inner">
    <% @img.each_with_index do |i|%>
    <% if i.gallery == "Art"%>
        <div class="active item">
            <%= image_tag (i.image.url) %>
        </div>

        <% i.next%> <!-- For incrementing the i value but it is not working-->
        <div class="item">
            <%= image_tag (i.image.url)%>   
        </div>
    <%end%> 
    <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want is in the `active item` it should display the first url of the image array and in the inactive item (which ll be active afterwards) should have the other images. It should not repeat the images. Here it is repeating the image since the value of `i` is not changing.

Comment: Try to trim the code down. `each_with_index` is most certainly working correctly. The error must be in your usage of it. But with all this unrelated noise it's hard to see.

Comment: <% @img.each_with_index do |i,j|%>`your part`<%end%>

Comment: Done with the trimming. 
@VenkatK: what is for J? Will j have the same value. I think again the answer will be the same. See the edit. i m rephrasing wat i exactly want.

Comment: Are you aware that `each_with_index` gives two parameters to the block? The object and the index. You are trying to increment the object??? Just calling the object `i` does not make it a counter.

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to understand what you want :) 
You can make your logic very simple, if you will separate your data.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousell-inner">
    <% @img.keep_if{|i| i.gallery == "Art"}.each do |i|%>
        <div class="active item">
            <%= image_tag (i.image.url) %>
        </div>
    <%end%>

    <% @img.keep_if{|i| i.gallery != "Art"}.each do |i|%>
        <div class="item">
            <%= image_tag (i.image.url)%>   
        </div>
    <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

And better to prepare your data in controller, not in view.

Comment: Actually ur code tells that display all the images which belong to the art gallery should display in the active part. So again it ll display all the images in a stack like pattern. Btw do u know how carousel works.?

Comment: in the div of item it should increment the value of i so that when the active part shifts to the other item it ll display the other image.

Answer (score 0):

ive found out the answer by doing it manually. First of all in the controller i ve found out all the images which belong to the `Art Gallery` by this code.

```
 @image = Image.find_all_by_gallery("Art")
```

Now to display the first element of the array `@image`, we can use the simply `@image.first` and then we can call that first element of the array in the active item of carousel. Then for the `item` part the basic thing to understand is that if we directly call and display all the elements of the array then the first element of the array will also be display in this part. So the repetition can happen. To avoid this we can do like this:

```
i = @image.count
@image[1..i]
```

So that the first element will not repeat in the `item' part of the carousel.
Hope it might help others. Thanks for giving time.

Answer (score 0):

I first thought you needed `each_with_index`, but actually, you are only interested in images from the `Art` gallery, no telling if the first image is actually an `Art` image, so I tried as follows:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousell-inner">
    <% art_images_counter = 0 %>
    <% @img.each do |image|%>
      <% if image.gallery == "Art" %>
        <% if art_images_counter == 0 %>
          <div class="active item">
            <%= image_tag (image.image.url) %>
          </div>
        <% else %>
          <div class="item">
            <%= image_tag (image.image.url)%>   
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <% art_images_counter += 1 %>
      <%end%> 
    <%end%>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not like that..!!! It is like that from the table `images` i m searching images which belong from the gallery `Art`. `Gallery` is an attribute of the image table. So in my view, i ve created a new view page in which i m displaying those images which belong to `Art` gallery. Similarly for all the galleries.

Comment: i'm assuming that u know the working of `twitter bootstrap's Carousel`. So accordingly the `class active item` is for showing the first element in the array. In my case whichever is the first image which belong to the art gallery will be displayed in the `class active item`. Anyway ive not found any wrong with the code ive written above. So u can understand from it.

Comment: What my answer does is: loop over all images, and put the first image where `gallery == 'Art'` in the first item of the carrousel, and all the other items in the other. So imho this should just work. Did you try this?